# vim - execute - shell command?

Tags: bash, shell, vim

I want to add a mapping which will visualize the output of a shell command in a new window.
the problem is the command is interrupted when moving the cursor to the top of the file.

```
:execute ":new \| set nonu \| 0r ! ls \| normal! gg"
```

I figured out that  the problem is with the execute command which considers the part from the symbol `!` to the rest of it as a **shell command** (`ls | normal! gg`) and that's why it shows an error when being executed.

How to prevent that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a command doesn't accept `<bar>` to separate the command. The normal way to fix this is wrap the command in a execute which does except bars

```
:execute ":new \| set nonu \| execute '0r ! ls' \| normal! gg"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can pull that off with `:execute`. But you can use [Clam](https://github.com/sjl/clam.vim) (e.g. `:Clam ls`) as a basis and edit `plugin/clam.vim` in order to fire a `gg` after execution of the shell command.